# Не запускается certbot на nginx из-за проблем с кодировкой

Tags: nginx, ssl, letsencrypt

Пытаюсь перевести сайт на wordpress на ssl. При попытке создания сертификата появляется следующая ошибка:

```
  sudo certbot --nginx certonly
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 814: invalid start byte
```

После гугления выяснилось, что дело в символах в кодировке, отличной от ASCII
Убрал, все, что можно.

```
grep -r -P '[^\x00-\x7f]' /etc/nginx
```

Ничего не выводит, но ошибка все равно остается?
Подскажите, как ее можно исправить?

Comment: Это полный текст ошибки?

Comment: может вы в конфигах пытаетесь домен `домен.рф` написать вместо `xn--d1acufc.xn--p1ai`?

Comment: Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log                                                                                                                                   
An unexpected error occurred:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 831: invalid start byte                                                                                               
Please see the logfiles in /var/log/letsencrypt for more details.

Comment: Домен не русский.